# Adding news lines when defining collection

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to define a collection (`dict`), and I would like to add a new line on each definition (for readability), Eg:

```
{{ $deployment := dict 
"Release" .Release 
"Chart" .Chart 
"Values" .Values }}
```

But when I do this, helm respond a parse error :

```
Error: parse error in "XXX": template: XXX:2: unclosed action
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: parse error in "XXX": template: XXX:2: unclosed action
```

Is there a way in HELM to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR;**

It's impossible to declare dict in multiline way, like with Perl *fat comma* operator.
 
Please check the [reference](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/dicts.html) of "Sprig: Template functions for Go templates."

Instead you could use this sort of hacky way to achieve similar result:

1. Keep each key value pair in separate line, in Global Values file for readability:

```html
# values.yaml
  -- 
  global:
  someMap:
    coffee: robusta
    origin: Angola
    crema: yes
```

2. Define helper template in _helpers.tpl:

```html
{{- define "mychart.labels.standard"}}
{{- $global := default (dict) .Values.global.someMap -}}
Release: {{ .Release.Name | quote }}
Chart: {{ .Chart.Name }}
Values:
{{- $global := default (dict) .Values.global.someMap -}} 
{{- range $key, $value := $global }}
  {{ $key }}: {{ $value }}
{{- end }}
{{- end -}}
```

3. Include it in another template:

```html
helm_data:
  {{- $global := default (dict) .Values.global -}}
  {{- range $key, $value := $global }}
    {{ $key }}: {{ $value }}
  {{- end }}
  {{ include "mychart.labels.standard" . | nindent 0 -}}
```

4. Render it to verify the result (helm template --name dict-chart .)

```html
---
# Source: mychart/templates/data_type.yaml
helm_data:
    someMap: map[crema:true origin:Angola coffee:robusta]
  
Release: "dict-chart"
Chart: mychart
Values:
    coffee: robusta
    crema: true
    origin: Angol
```

Comment: Thanks, thats the hack I was looking for.

Comment: Is this still relevant today since 2019? Having only one-line dictionaries is a very bad limitation :(

Answer (score 4):

I achieved this by defining the dict first and then setting one key per line.

```
{{- $myDict := dict "" "" -}}
{{- $_ := set $myDict "myKey1" "myValue1" -}}
{{- $_ := set $myDict "myKey2" "myValue2" -}}
{{- $_ := set $myDict "myKey3" "myValue3" -}}
{{- $_ := set $myDict "myKey4" "myValue4" -}}
```

Bonus Tip: Since dict `get` function is available seemingly in only helm3 and later, you can use this hack to get a value from a dict to a string.

```
{{/* Hack needed until helm 3 which has 'get' for 'dict' */}}
{{- $myValue3Var := pluck "myKey3" $myDict | first -}}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! This is brilliant! With this trick, along with the "include" command", I can finally make Helm templates modular without resorting to global "Values".

Comment: Thanks man :D I'm glad I could help. I mostly figured this out by reading the docs https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/

Answer (score 1):

It seems it's impossible to do so. The Helm templating system is basically the Go templating system. As stated in the [Go templating docs](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/):

> Except for raw strings, actions may not span newlines, although comments can.

Answer (score 1):

For people coming across this question, this functionality works in recent versions of HELM. For me, OPs example works as-is (Helm v3.8.2).

(I came across this question myself due to a mismatched `)` in my template.)